# show max row result sql with 2 'where' conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

i have table master_pangkat

```
id_pangkat  name
-----------------
a1          |Chef
a2          |Cleaning Service
a3          |Cashier
```

and i have table peg_pangkat

```
id nip id_pangkat year
----------------------
1  2001   a2        2012  
2  2001   a3        2015 
3  2012   a1        2016
4  2012   a1        2016
```

i want to show max id from table peg_pangkat where nip = 2001

i've tried this code

```
select * from peg_pangkat join master_pangkat on
    peg_pangkat.id_pangkat=master_pangkat.id
    where peg_pangkat.id=(select max(peg_pangkat.id) from peg_pangkat) ;
```

but it's show

- 4 2012 a1 2016

then when i add another where condition where nip=2001
it showed no result

```
     select * from peg_pangkat join master_pangkat on
            peg_pangkat.id_pangkat=master_pangkat.id
            where nip=2001
 and peg_pangkat.id=(select max(peg_pangkat.id) from   peg_pangkat) ;
```

and the result i wanna show is

- 2 2001 a3 2015

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `WHERE` clause in the subquery.

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM peg_pangkat pp
INNER JOIN master_pangkat mp
    ON pp.id_pangkat = mp.id
WHERE
    pp.nip = 2001
    AND pp.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM peg_pangkat WHERE nip = pp.nip);
```

As a side note, you should use meaningful aliases on your tables to improve readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method:

```
select *
from peg_pangkat p join
     master_pangkat m
     on p.id_pangkat = m.id
where p.nip = 2001
order by p.id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: only the p table show max result and joined m still the first row